# Draw texture with shader

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, shader, opentk

I want to draw a texture in my shader but get an exception (see below).

I have following code:

```
int vertexArray;

//Pointer to Buffers
int vertexBuffer;
int colorBuffer;
int coordBuffer;

int texUniform; //Pointer to Uniform

int texture; //Pointer to Texture
```

Init

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
texture = LoadPNG("Resources\\Test.png");
//...
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (float)All.Nearest);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (float)All.Nearest);
GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

vertexArray = GL.GenVertexArray();
GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArray);

float[] TexCoords = new float[] {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
}; //(Array.Length = 2*3)

//Arrays for Vertex (3*3) and Color (4*3)
//GenBuffer, BindBuffer and BufferData for Color and Vertex

coordBuffer = GL.GenBuffer();
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.TextureBuffer, coordBuffer);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.TextureBuffer, (IntPtr)(sizeof(float) * TexCoords.Length), TexCoords, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

//Load shader

texUniform = GL.GetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex");
GL.Uniform1(texUniform, 0);
GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
```

Draw

```
GL.UseProgram(shaderProgram);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texture);

GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexBuffer);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);

GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, colorBuffer);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);

GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.TextureBuffer, coordBuffer);
GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, Vector2.SizeInBytes, 0);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);

GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 6); //<------ Exception

GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

I get a System.AccessViolationException at `GL.DrawArrays(...);`. I suspect that i haven't loaded a buffer correctly or used a pointer in an incorrect way. The exception is caused by changes i did to get a texture with texture coordinates into the shader, that means vertex and color buffer are working.

I'm not sure what i am doing wrong. I tried different things with the shader but it seems it doesn't matter what i am doing with the shader...

At my last try:
Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 vColor;
out vec2 texCoords[];

void main(){
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
  texCoords[0] = texCoord;
  vColor = color;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core
in vec4 vColor;
in vec2 texCoords[];

uniform sampler2D tex;

out vec4 fColor;

void main(void)
{
  //fColor = vColor;
  fColor = texture2D(Texture0, texCoords[0].st);
}
```

GetShaderInfoLog and GetProgramInfoLog do not return any errors when i comment `GL.DrawArrays(...)` and run the application.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: any errors when you compiled/linked the program? see the [shader log](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetShaderInfoLog) after compiling and the [program log](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramInfoLog) after linking

Comment: @ratchetfreak When i comment the GL.DrawArrays, i get "0{11}: error C1035: assignment of incompatible types" (when i change `vec4` in `vec4 texCoords[]` (fragment and vertex) to `vec2` there are no ShaderInfoLog and ProgramInfoLog errors). I edited it in my question to `vec2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do not enable client state vertex arrays.

#### Replace the following:

```
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
...
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);
...
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);
```

#### With:

```
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
...
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
...
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

At present, you are telling GL to source vertex attributes from `glVertexPointer (...)`, `glColorPointer (...)` and `glTexCoordPointer (...)`, none of which you actually have setup.

You *might* be able to get away with enabling the client state: `ArrayCap.VertexArray` because many drivers alias that to attribute **0**, but the others are a recipe for disaster. Nevertheless, until you remove the `EnableClientState (...)` calls you are going to continue crashing.

---

### Update:

I missed something in your texture coordinate setup...

#### You also need to replace this line:

```
GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, Vector2.SizeInBytes, 0);
```

#### With this:

```
GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
```

Comment: It works now :) Should i call `EnableVertexAttribArray` before `VertexAttribPointer` or after or doesn't matter? And if i don't need to enable the client state, for what is this client state used?

Comment: You should not call it at all. Those states are for the ***legacy*** fixed-function vertex pipeline.